# Remove page from Google Listings using robots.txt file

Tags: search, indexing, robots.txt

Is this the correct way to do this - below is my txt file, would this prevent Google from indexing my admin directory as well as oldpage.php?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: http://www.mysite.com/oldpage.php
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely correct except single file restriction.

`User-agent: *` : means for all crawler

`Allow: /` : allow access of full site

`Disallow: /admin/` : restrict to admin directory

`Disallow: /oldpage.php` : restrict to oldpage.php